# How to display all images from a blog article

Tags: shopware

I am trying to display all the images from a blog article in the blog listing page.

Currently it only displays the image **marked as preview** in the ***shopware backend > blog article configuration > Image configuration***. But I also need to display the others if you select more than one.

I have been trying to modify the **box.tpl** file from the **blog folder**, the **detail.tpl**, and even the **Blog.php** file under **Shopware > Controllers > Frontend** but didn't have luck.

In the Blog.php file under the index method I saw this piece of code but not sure if this one does the trick

```
//adding thumbnails to the blog article

            if (empty($blogArticle['media'][0]['mediaId'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $mediaId = $blogArticle['media'][0]['mediaId'];

            if (!isset($medias[$mediaId])) {
                continue;
            }
```

I am not a shopware expert so any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write your own plugin and override the index method of the Blog Controller.

You can take a look at the Blog Controller's [detailAction](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.5/engine/Shopware/Controllers/Frontend/Blog.php#L328-L336) how to get all media images.

In your above example you're just getting the first image with `[0]`, but you would need to loop trough all images like in the [detailAction](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.5/engine/Shopware/Controllers/Frontend/Blog.php#L328-L336).

You may also have a look at the [Shopware developer video trainings](https://www.udemy.com/user/shopware-ag/) on Udemy and the [Shopware developer documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you say "to write your own plugin" this means to create a new controller and a method in it to override the index one from the blog controller?